# How can I make sure slidetoggle only fires when the same element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got three blocks, when a block is clicked a div slides open using slideToggle. When the same block is clicked the div closes, this works as it should, but if the second block is clicked the data that belongs to the second block is loaded, but it instantly slides back up (closes).

How can I make sure that it only closes when the same block is clicked twice and just switches data / stays open when another block is clicked?

My html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse haven">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background text-center" style="background-color: #ececec;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="01">
              <span>Haven & Industrie</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse openbaar">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background vk-iconbox-striped text-center" style="background-color: #faf5f5;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="02">
              <span>Openbare Ruimte</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse landmeten">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background text-center" style="background-color: #ececec;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="03">
              <span>Landmeten</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vk-what-we-do-section vk-section vk-section-style-2 vk-section-style-3 tabwrapper">

            </div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.handmouse').on('click', function(e){
        var alias = $(this).attr("data-attribute");
        $.post("ajax/blokken.php", {
          dienstnaam : alias
        }, function(data) {
            $(".tabwrapper").html(data);
            MasonryItem.init();
        });
        $('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".tabwrapper").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

The three blocks all can be identified by their last classes (haven, openbaar, landmeten).